# Radio button change table row background color when selected and go back to normal when selecting another radio button without 'hovering"interfering

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, html-table, radio-button

I looked at other similar questions but it did not help me. I want to change the table row background color when I select radio button to blue. When I click another radio button I want the other to change back to normal and the one I click to change to blue. As of now, when I select a radio button it just act like a hover and make the row blue as soon as I move the mouse away it goes back to its original color. I want to be able to hover and click:

```
     <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $("tr").not(':first').hover(
      function () {
        $(this).css("background","lightblue");
      }, 
      function () {
        $(this).css("background","");
      }
    );


    $('input:radio').change(function () {
        $(this).closest('tr').siblings().css('background-color', 'white')
                     .end().css('background-color', 'darkblue');
    });

    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('input:radio').change(function () {
    var parentTr = $(this).closest('tr');
    parentTr.siblings().css('background-color', 'white');
    parentTr.css('background-color', 'darkblue');
});
```

You can also use `end`:

```
$('input:radio').change(function () {
    $(this).closest('tr').siblings().css('background-color', 'white')
                         .end().css('background-color', 'darkblue');
});
```

But it's usually harder to read and maintain.

- Note that you better use css class instead of change the css inline.

Comment: im not understanding to i add this function or replace mine

Comment: Its giving me the same problem..when i click the radio button I want it to maintain that blue even if i move my mouse away until i click another radio button. the first code you gave me does the same thimg by original code do

Comment: @user1392576. Weird... can you give me a demo to work with at http://jsfiddle.net to reproduce it

Comment: im sorry...i know whats wrong by i don't know  how to incorporate it in my code...i will edit the code

Comment: @user1392576. Come on! that change change the whole question!!! and please create a demo.

Comment: im sorry...i didn't know.. so how do you create a demo..im new to this

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>

<body>

<table>
<tr><td><input class="rad" type="radio" name="blah" value="1"/>One</td></tr>
<tr><td><input class="rad" type="radio" name="blah" value="2"/>Two</td></tr>
<tr><td><input class="rad" type="radio" name="blah" value="3"/>Three</td></tr>
</table>

</body>

</html>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("tr").not(':first').hover(
function () {
if($(this).css("background-color") != 'darkblue'){
$(this).css("background","lightblue");
}
}, 
function () {
if($(this).css("background-color") != 'darkblue'){
$(this).css("background","");
}
}
);
$(".rad").unbind("click").click(function(){
$('tr').css('background-color', 'white');
$(this).closest('tr').css('background-color', 'darkblue');
});
</script>
```

Comment: but still. since i have my hovering function as well, I can't maintain the dark blue color when my mouse leave the area