# A radiobutton click refreshes/changes small area of website

Tags: php, javascript, html

I'm looking for a way to have a radio button containing certain filters that when clicked would change an area of the website without completely refreshing the page.

Imagine radiobuttons to the left on the navigation while a table on the right of it that changes smoothly when the radiobuttons are clicked.

Could somebody point me in the right direction with what I need for it to work?

Comment: check the following link....
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10690898/radio-button-change-table-row-bkgrnd-clor-when-slctd-and-go-bck-to-nrml-whn-slc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one more example is here....

```
http://interestingwebs.blogspot.in/2009/01/how-to-show-and-hide-html-elements.html

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10690898/radio-button-change-table-row-bkgrnd-clor-when-slctd-and-go-bck-to-nrml-whn-slc
```